# nltk package returns TypeError: 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I'm using nltk==3.4.1 and I'm executing this code:

```
import nltk.corpus as stopwords
import nltk
nltk.download("stopwords")
sw = stopwords.words('english')
```

And I get this error (without the third line I get the same error too):

> [nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /home/kamran/nltk_data...
>
> [nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
>
> sw = stopwords.words('english')
>
> TypeError: 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not callable

I'm using a virtual envirenement which is ***not*** in */home/kamran/nltk_data* directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error from first line. Change your code into:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk

sw = stopwords.words('english')
```

Comment: Thanks sooo much! and what a mistake:/